# MAMP return error 500 even if display error is set to on

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, mamp

I'm facing an issue with MAMP,

Whatever error type I get in PHP (notice, fatal etc...), MAMP returns a 500 Internal error, even when I put the following at the beginning of my script :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I found the solution myself.

I had to directly set 'display_errors' to 'On' in the **php.ini** file.

It didn't work just by adding these lines in my script.

Comment: That's only an issue if the error happens before your PHP code runs (parse error, upload limits hit...)